# Having trouble exporting my Application Insight data to SQL table?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-application-insights

I am viewing Applications Insight through Visual Studio 2017 View->Other Windows -.Applications Insight.

Can i export this data from Visual Studio to a sql table to perform more detailed queries ?

Comment: Please refer to answer below, and let me know if you have any concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to import data into sql table since Application insights has its own table for these data. You can also perform more detailed queries on these data via the sql-like language [kusto query language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/tutorial?pivots=azuremonitor).

To do that, you need to go to azure portal -> your application insights -> Logs. In Logs, you can see some tables like `traces`, `requests` etc. -> then you can write your own query to do anything like you do in sql table:

[image]

By the way, there is no direct way to export these data into sql. If you want to do that, you should export these data into azure storage first(it's called [Continuous Export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-telemetry#setup)), then use other methods to export them into sql. But I don't suggest it, people should always use the built-in logs table in application insights.